# Pass parameter and model to component view in PagedListPager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i am traying to use PagedList in asp.net core

Function List in view component name : AdvListViewComponent.cs

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int page = 1)
    {

        var adv = _db.advertisements.OrderByDescending(i => i.AdvId); 
        return View(adv.ToList().ToPagedList(page , 6 ));
    }
```

in asp.net mvc i use this code To go to the next page ( My List function was Index in controller)

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

how  can i  pass paremeter `page` and Model to View Component InvokeAsync (AdvList)  AdvListViewComponent.cs  using lambda and PagedListPager
to go to the next page

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to use a complex model for the View. The complex model will carry all the necessary date from the action to the View. For example:

**View Model:**

```
public class MyViewModel {
   public MyViewModel(){
      advList = new List<Adv>();
   }

   public int pageIndex {get; set;}
   public int pageSize {get; set;}
   public int TotalCount {get; set;}
   public string OrderBy {get; set;}
   public List<Adv> advList {get; set;}
}
```

**Action:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> InvokeAsync(MyViewModel model)
{
    var adv = _db.advertisements
        .skip(model.pageIndex * model.pageSize)
        .Take(model.pageSize)
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.AdvId); 
    
    model.advList = adv.ToList().ToPagedList(model.pageIndex + 1 , model.pageSize)
    return View(model);
}
```

This allows you to only load the data for the current page and not all the data. Then in the **View:**

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.advList, page => Url.Action("Index", 
    new { Model.pageIndex, sortOrder = Model.OrderBy }))
```

Now if you click the pager then in the action's parameter the `pageIndex` and `OrderBy` will be auto populated from the UI.

This way you can send-receive multiple parameters between view and controller.

Comment: Thank you for your response its very good solution for pagination . in my issu i want to pass value to my view component  instead of url action like this @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Component.InvokeAsync("AdvList", new { page })) My View Component Function located in folder Of ViewComponent->AdvListViewComponent not in Controller to use url action ..but  when i use that i get error